# Android Studio, changing background theme by command line?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

In Android Studio, we can change the background theme from `Preferences->Appearance` (in mac OS). But I want to change it faster, so is it possible to change the background theme by script with command line ?

Comment: Why do you need it? IDE stores color scheme setting in ` ~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.2/options/colors.scheme.xml`, but loads that file only on start. After that the theme could be changed in runtime only (from inside IntelliJ IDEA)

Comment: @KonstantinAnnikov, since COVID19, working from home is getting popular, I'm used to switching IDE color schemes between 2~3 stored schemes by observing sun light brightness because my screen is just next to the window.